# Program implementing stack exits with "code=3221225477"

Tags: c++, stack

The program is just a simple implementation of a stack that keeps popping until the stack is empty.  It pops the last letter and then crashes; although, technically it does what it's supposed to do.  I'd just like to know why I'm getting the error code 3221225477 and how to fix it.  I'm sure it's something simple.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

//Stack implementation in C++ using stack library
int main()
{
    stack<string> s;

    s.push("A"); //Insert "A" in the stack
    s.push("B"); //Insert "B" in the stack
    s.push("C"); //Insert "C" in the stack
    s.push("D"); //Insert "D" in the stack

    //Returns the number of elements present in the stack 
    cout << "Stack size is " << s.size() << endl;

    //Prints the top of the stack ("D")
    cout << "Top element is: " << s.top() << endl;

    while (!s.empty())
    {
        cout << "Popping " << s.top() << endl;
        s.pop();
        cout << "Top element is now " << s.top() << endl;
        cout << "The stack size is now " << s.size() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: what happens in your loop when `s.size()` is equal to `1`?

Comment: `s.pop(); cout << "Top element is now " << s.top() << endl;` -- You pop(), the stack is empty.  Oops on the `top()`.

Comment: After popping the last item you will call `top()` on the empty stack again.

Comment: You only need one element in the stack to encounter the problem. Starting with the smallest possible test cases is a good habit.

Comment: I think the root cause of the issue is printing the first item before the loop starts.  Usually the loop would be `while (!s.empty()) { do stuff with s.top();  s.pop(); }`, but your loop does the odd `"Top element is:"` printing before the loop starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here if the current element is the last element, you `pop()` and then access `top()` with the stack with no elements.

```
cout << "Popping " << s.top() << endl;
s.pop();
cout << "Top element is now " << s.top() << endl;
cout << "The stack size is now " << s.size() << endl;
```

To

```
cout << "Popping " << s.top() << endl;
s.pop();
if (!s.empty()) {
  cout << "Top element is now " << s.top() << endl;
  cout << "The stack size is now " << s.size() << endl;
}
```

**Note:**

Just be careful whenever you try to access elements of the stack, like here:

```c
cout << "Top element is: " << s.top() << endl;
```

Right now, this is not a problem because the stack has items, but it would be a case of undefined behavior if the stack was empty when this line was called.